# How to upload a file using django FileBrowser

Tags: django, django-filebrowser

In the description of the django app called [FileBrowser](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser), it says that the app allows to "browse directories on your server and upload/delete/edit/rename files".

I think that I managed to install the app correctly following the [documentation](http://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html).
But when I access /admin/filebrowser/browse/  I can't see how to upload a file. There are no buttons or anything.

If I manually put a file in the uploads directory, it does show up on the admin interface though.

Is there a command or some code I need to type to enable the upload in FileBrowser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have everything set up correctly it should resemble something similar to this:

https://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/wiki/screenshots

Comment: well I'm trying to upload files using FileBrowser and not creat a seperate app for that. As it is mentioned in the description of FileBrowser it should handle that.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. You're purely looking to use it for the Admin page and not also for the django app itself. I edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah they are both installed. If I manually put files in the uploads folder they show up in the Admin page but I cannot figure out how to upload the files from the Admin page.

Comment: If you have everything installed and set up correctly it should look something like this https://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/wiki/screenshots

Comment: Thank you! These screenshots helped me figure it out. if I use the url /admin/filebrowser/upload/ I can access the page from which I can upload files. I don't know why there isn't a link from the Admin page though. Wanna edit your answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score -1):

I think the best-practice is to use the Django native forms.FileField class in your form. This class manages the whole file upload process saving the uploaded file into the folder you want. Take a look to Django specific documentation:

[Django File Uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/)

E.g.:

```
# In forms.py...

from django import forms 

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
     title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
     file = forms.FileField()
```

Comment: That was not his question.